# Setting link href from child image src using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `.wrap()` to create a link around each image within a certain `<div>`, and I need to set that link's `href` to be equal to that image's `src` value.
I figured out how to do the selection and the substitution, but I can't figure out how to extract the `src` value.

This is the html structure:

```
<div class="divclass">
    <img src="path1" />
    <img src="path2" />
    <img src="path3" />
</div>
```

and the desired outcome is

```
<div class="divclass">
    <a class="linkclass" href="path1">
        <img src="path1" />
    </a>
    <a class="linkclass" href="path2">
        <img src="path2" />
    </a>
    <a class="linkclass" href="path3">
        <img src="path3" />
    </a>
</div>
```

The easy part is creating the link around the images, and I use `.wrap()` to do so.
Next I need to set the `href` value, and I can use `.attr` for that, but I don't know how to extract the value of `src` within the same call. This is what I have so far:

```
$('.divclass img').wrap("<a class=\"linkclass\" href="" />");
$('a.linkclass').attr("href", $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
```

but this is not working. I suspect I'm using `$(this)` wrong, but can't figure out how/why.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and read through it. There are a few things that are worth knowing in these few lines. It is much like CephalidOne's solution but might be a bit easier to understand.

```
$('div.divclass img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.wrap('<a href="' + $this.attr('src') + '"></a>');
});
```

See it work: http://jsfiddle.net/AAdWH/

Comment: you are right, this explains what I've been trying to do. Thanks!
I ended up using @CephalidOne's solution as I liked it all in one line.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.divclass img').wrap(function() {
  return '<a class="linkclass" href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of :

```
$(this).find('img')
```

use:

```
$(this).children('img')
```

and your wrap is formatted incorrectly.

so in the end your code would be:

```
$('.divclass img').wrap("<a class='linkclass' />");
$('a.linkclass').attr("href", $(this).children('img').attr('src'));
```

or change your code completely:

example [(the fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ZygRd/):

```
$('.divclass').children('img')
    .each(function(){
        var $this = $(this)
        $this.wrap("<a class='linkclass'/>")
        $this.parent('.linkclass').attr("href", $this.attr('src')); 
     });
```