# Add full link to image

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can add full link to all my images with jQuery?

```
<img src="/pic/img.png"></img>
```

To:

```
<a href="/pic/img.png"><img src="/pic/img.png"></img><a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time try to google things a bit before posting a question. Anyways we're always glad to help!

Comment: You can take help from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318715/setting-link-href-from-child-image-src-using-jquery

Comment: One comment, HTML images tag must **NOT** be closed like </img>, Just use <img src=".." />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery wrap function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "img" ).wrap(function() {
    return "<a href='" + $( this ).attr("src") + "'></a>";
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery wrap api](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap( "<a href='"+$(this).attr('src')+"'></a>" );
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the href attribute in the img tag itself

```
<img src="/pic/img.png" href="/pic/img.png">
```

Comment: Because I need add lightbox to my images

Comment: Also I don't think href is a valid attribute for img tags

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
$("img").each(function(){
 var source = $(this).attr(src);
 $(this).wrap('<a href="'+source+'"></a>');
});
```

Comment: The src attribute must wrap with qoute or double qoute